# How to load java AppleScript engine dynamically from Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

Later versions of Java (7, 8) do not include Apples AppleScript script engine and it is required to modify a java projects META-INF services.

So, two questions:

1. How would I do this from Clojure code in a REPL
2. How would I set this once (statically) so it is automatic anytime I start a project namespace in a REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle JDK 8 for Mac OS X still comes with an AppleScript engine and you can use it dynamically from Clojure without configuring `META-INF/services`. The following example demonstrates a say-hello script.

```
user> (import 'apple.applescript.AppleScriptEngineFactory)
apple.applescript.AppleScriptEngineFactory

user> (let [engine (.getScriptEngine (AppleScriptEngineFactory.))]
        (.eval engine "say \"hello\""))
nil
```

Comment: thanks. I just found [this](https://github.com/benashford/clojure-scripting/issues/2) as well.